# Bull Board UI stuck on "Loading"

Tags: node.js, redis, server, node-redis

> In localhost the im using **`/admin`** route, and it displays the Bull board.

> But On Production Environment ( which is hosted on **AWS** ) , It is stuck on `Loading...` phase

[image]
[image]

> Please Give me info what Im doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

I was using http://localhost:/admin
( as bull board is configured on /admin route )

But on Production Env. My was using http://**ip**/admin and getting error

I searched and figured it out that I need to pass port number with IP.

So Solution is:

```
https://current-ip:4000/admin
```